# Maximal tori in lie groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

How would one prove that a maximal torus in a lie group is a maximal abelian subgroup?
For example, in the specific cases of SO(n) or SU(n). I know that the maximal torus of SO(2n) and SO(2n+1) is Tn and that of SU(n) is Tn-1, and by definition, the maximal torus is an abelian subgroup, but I'm having trouble showing that it is maximal.

Comment: I think the statement is false, stated in this way. For instance in $\mathbb{C}^*$ a maximal torus (i.e. maximal compact connected abelian Lie subgroup) is given by $S^1$, which is not maximal abelian, since $\mathbb{C}^*$ itself is abelian. This of course generalizes to $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ for higher $n$.

Comment: I think you mean that the lie algebra corresponding to maximal torus in a Lie group is a maximal abelian subalgebra.